# Getting IllegalStateException when creating dynamic Fields using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my program, I am generating dynamic form names based on the number of `feedbacks` I get. I am then taking the `satisfaction`, `comment` and `feedbackId` inputs. They are different for each iteration. This is giving me an `IllegalStateException` error.

My HTML form is:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/heart2heart/token/__${tokenId}__/}" method="post">               
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none;"></th>
                <th th:text="#{service.desc}">Service</th>
                <th th:text="#{feedback.description}">Feedback</th>
                <th th:text="#{visit.date}">Date of Visit</th>
                <th th:text="#{repr.name}">FU Repr</th>
                <th th:text="#{resolution.response}">Response</th>
                <th th:text="#{resolution.satisfactionLevel}">Satisfaction</th>
                <th th:text="#{resolution.comment}">Comment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="feedback, feedbackStat : *{feedbacks}">
                <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" th:field="*{feedbacks[__${feedbackStat.index}__].feedbackId}" th:value="${feedback.id}" /></td>
                <td th:text="${feedback.service.description}">Steel</td>
                <td th:text="${feedback.description}">Problem</td>
                <td th:text="${feedback.visits[0].date}">12/08/2015</td>
                <td th:text="${feedback.visits[0].repr.fullName}">XYZ</td>
                <td th:text="${feedback.receipt.resolutions[0].response}">response</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" th:field="*{feedbacks[__${feedbackStat.index}__].satisfaction}" th:text="#{global.yes}" value="SATISFIED">Yes</input></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" th:field="*{feedbacks[__${feedbackStat.index}__].satisfaction}" th:text="#{global.no}" value="NOT SATISFIED">No</input></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><textarea th:field="*{feedbacks[__${feedbackStat.index}__].comment}" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="addRow" th:text="#{button.submit}"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{tokenId}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSatisfaction(@PathVariable int tokenId, @Valid ReceiptForm receiptForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    try {
        for (SatisfactionForm satisfactionForm : receiptForm.getFeedbacks()) {
        Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
        feedback.setId(satisfactionForm.getFeedbackId());
        Feedback feedback1 = heart2heartService.getFeedbackById(feedback);
        Resolution resolution = new Resolution();
        resolution.setId(feedback1.getReceipt().getResolutions().get(0).getId());
        resolution.setSatisfactionLevel(satisfactionForm.getSatisfaction().name());
        resolution.setComment(satisfactionForm.getComment());
        heart2heartService.addSatisfaction(resolution);
        model.addAttribute("success", "Satisfaction added for tokenId " + tokenId);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception :: ", e);
    }
    return "success2";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{tokenId}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSatisfaction(@PathVariable int tokenId, Model model) {
    Token token = new Token();
    token.setId(tokenId);
    try {
        model.addAttribute("feedbacks", heart2heartService.getFeedbacksByToken(token));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception :: ", e);
    }
    return "heart2heart/closeFeedback";
}
```

My forms are:

```
public class ReceiptForm {
    private List<SatisfactionForm> feedbacks = new ArrayList<SatisfactionForm>();

    public List<SatisfactionForm> getFeedbacks() {
    return feedbacks;
    }

    public void setFeedbacks(List<SatisfactionForm> feedbacks) {
    this.feedbacks = feedbacks;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SatisfactionForm {
    public static enum Satisfaction {
        NOT_SATISFIED, SATISFIED
    }

    private String comment;
    private int feedbackId;
    private Satisfaction satisfaction;

    public String getComment() {
    return comment;
    }

    public int getFeedbackId() {
    return feedbackId;
    }

    public Satisfaction getSatisfaction() {
    return satisfaction;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
    }

    public void setFeedbackId(int feedbackId) {
    this.feedbackId = feedbackId;
    }

    public void setSatisfaction(Satisfaction satisfaction) {
    this.satisfaction = satisfaction;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'feedbacks[0]' available as request attribute
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the form-backing bean in your Thymeleaf template.
You are using the `*{}` operator to access fields of the bean, but Thymeleaf does not know
which bean you want to use. To resolve the error, add a `th:object` to your form.
Assuming that `heart2heartService.getFeedbacksByToken(token)` returns a `ReceiptForm` your form would look like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/heart2heart/token/__${tokenId}__/}" method="post" th:object="${feedbacks}">
```